# getting 404 error in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have started with react-router-dom. my main page rendered successfully but when I am clicking on hyper provided by `Link` component it is not redirecting but if I hit url manually it is giving me 404 error. please help me in this?

here is my config file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
//import rootReducer from './reducers'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import logger from "redux-logger"
import {fetchUsers} from "./action/UserAction"
import {fetchChart} from "./action/ChartAction"
import {fetchNames} from "./action/SearchAction"
import reducer from "./reducers"
import routes from "./routes"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())
const store= createStore(reducer,middleware)

store.dispatch(fetchUsers());
store.dispatch(fetchChart());
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter >
      {routes}
    </BrowserRouter>

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

my routes file

```
import App from "./pages/App"
import Users from "./pages/Users"
import Charts from "./pages/Charts"
import React from "react"
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"
export default (
  <switch>
  <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  <Route path="/users" component={Users}/>
    <Route path="/charts" name="charts" component={Charts}/>
 </switch>

);
```

App.js

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import React from "react"
const App = () =>(

<div>
<h1> this is main page </h1>
<Link to="charts">charts</Link>
</div>
)

export default App
```

Users.js

```
import React from "react"
const User = () =>(
    <div>
    <h1> this is user </h1>
    </div>
)

export default User
```

Charts.js

```
import React from "react"
const Chart = () => (
    <h1> this is chart </h1>
)

export default Chart
```

**UPDATE 1**:
I do not know what is going on. but I alter the sequence in routes.js it is working by clicking on url. but still if I hit the url manually or refresh there it is still not working. below is my updated routes.js

```
import App from "./pages/App"
import Users from "./pages/Users"
import Charts from "./pages/Charts"
import React from "react"
import { Route,Switch } from "react-router-dom"

export default (
  <Switch>
    <Route  path="/charts"  component={Charts}/>
    <Route  path="/users" component={Users}/>
  <Route path="/" component={App}/>


 </Switch>

);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
if I am using exact path then sequence does not matter. I think I didn't understand use of exact path correctly. but still while hitting url manually or refreshing is not working for me
 my final routes.js

```
import App from "./pages/App"
import Users from "./pages/Users"
import Charts from "./pages/Charts"
import React from "react"
import { Route,Switch } from "react-router-dom"

export default (
  <Switch>


  <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
  <Route  exact path="/charts"  component={Charts}/>
  <Route exact path="/users" component={Users}/>

 </Switch>

);
```

Comment: Is the link changing even if its not redirecting, and are there any errors inconsole

Comment: Ya url is changing and no error

Comment: Can you import {Switch} from 'react-router' and replace `switch` with `Switch`

Comment: Is it from react-router-dom or react-router? I tried with former. No luck

Comment: I use it from `react-router`

Comment: tried.No help..:(

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Am I missing any install? I installed react-router-dom and history and react-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling I got a SO post saying that if my data is not mapping from backend I should use HashRouter. So I changed my browser so I changed my code to this. but I don't know why browser router didn't work

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter >
      {routes}
    </HashRouter>

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack add this

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

when using BrowserRouter "**historyApiFallback**" should be true