# react-router-dom gives me 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I started adding routes to my app, the problem is that even after I render them I cannot access them (get a 404). I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939304/react-js-react-router-dom-results-in-404), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349261/not-found-page-react-router-v4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263511/getting-404-error-in-react-router-dom), but I cannot make it work. This is my index

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';

const app = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and my `App.jsx` is just

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/foo' render = {() => <h1>foo</h1>} />
          <Route exact path = '/' render = {() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
        </Switch>
        <a href = '/foo'>Go to foo</a>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

In theory, if I click on the anchor tag, I should redirected to the `foo` path, but instead I get a 404. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: remove exact path from '/foo' - just use path = '/foo'. Also your spacing between path and  =

Comment: you cannot use `<a href="/foo">` here. after you click the link your browser asks server for resource with same URL but you need navigation occuring on client side with React Router

Comment: @LukeWalker `<Route path = '/foo' render = {() => <h1>foo</h1>} />`, gives me the same problem

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `<Route>`. it's just how browser works. there are few different approaches how work around that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Link` [component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) of `react-router-dom`:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to="/foo">Go to foo</Link>
```

This will generate an `<a>` tag but will respect the client routing

Comment: Thanks Sagiv, that actually solves it. Do you know why if I directly type `localhost/foo` on my browser I get a `404`?

Comment: It's just how browser works: you click the link(type the url) and browser by default is going to given URL. But your server is not configured to return page for every single client-side route. If you had configured your routes having hash sign(#) then browser would not send request to server

Comment: You need to configure your server to return the same `html` file (your app entry point) for every route.

Comment: what type of server are you running?

Comment: This is just local testing

Comment: yeah but if you type `localhost` in your browser there must be a server running under the hood that response with an `html` file to the request. did you use a starter kit or something like `create-react-app`?

Comment: I'm running this with `flask`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution!

Remove `exact` from `exact path = '/foo'`

With a Tag, page will get loaded, hence better to use `<Link to='/foo'>roster</Link>`

Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7149x0oqlx) which you can refer

Answer (score 1):

You can import {Link} from react-router it gives an a tag and you can redirect